# Segfault taking element from QList

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I get a SEGFAULT at the first line in the if-block, takeFirst().

```
if (!sendQueue.isEmpty()) {
    QString nxtcmd = sendQueue.takeFirst();
    port->write(nxtcmd.toLatin1());
    port->flush();
}
```

I have code pushing 96 command strings into the queue with

```
if (completionHandlerQueue.empty()) {
…
} else {
    sendQueue.append(cmd_str);
}
```

The latter happens in my main GUI code. The first bit is called by a signal by QExtSerialPort (when data is there to be read).

sendQueue is a member and declared as such:

```
class SB::ModuleCommunicator : public QObject
{
 …
 private:
     …
     QStringList sendQueue;
```

Now I'm not using threads and I assumed the Qt Event Loop would make everything work smoothly, but the full backtrace does tell me that there are in fact 3 threads.
According to documentation, Qt Containers are only thread-safe for read only access.
But the Queue is already full with all 96 strings when it crashes. So I don't think anything is appending while the list is being modified.

Is this a thread issue? How can I find out?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
0   _int_malloc malloc.c    3530    0x7ffff61c7410  
1   __GI___libc_malloc  malloc.c    2924    0x7ffff61c9f95  
2   QListData::detach(int)  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4    0   0x7ffff6cd397b  
3   QList<QString>::detach_helper   qlist.h 709 0x412169    
4   QList<QString>::detach_helper   qlist.h 725 0x411cf2    
5   QList<QString>::detach  qlist.h 139 0x411e72    
6   QList<QString>::begin   qlist.h 267 0x423610    
7   QList<QString>::first   qlist.h 282 0x422dda    
8   QList<QString>::takeFirst   qlist.h 490 0x422885    
9   SB::ModuleCommunicator::handleMsg   ModuleCommunicator.cpp  116 0x41f9be    
10  SB::ModuleCommunicator::onReadyRead ModuleCommunicator.cpp  393 0x421f4d    
11  SB::ModuleCommunicator::qt_static_metacall  moc_ModuleCommunicator.cpp  52  0x435e1e    
12  QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4    0   0x7ffff6dc9281  
13  QextSerialPortPrivate::_q_canRead   qextserialport.cpp  313 0x40c505    
14  QextSerialPort::qt_static_metacall  moc_qextserialport.cpp  97  0x40dbfa    
15  QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4    0   0x7ffff6dc9281  
16  QSocketNotifier::activated(int) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4    0   0x7ffff6e162fe  
17  QSocketNotifier::event(QEvent*) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4    0   0x7ffff6dd260b  
18  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 0   0x7ffff72d7894  
19  QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 0   0x7ffff72dc713  
20  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4    0   0x7ffff6db4e9c  
... <More>
```

**UDPATE:**

So it seems I have a transient error here. Now it crashed at

```
for (int i = 0; i < msgBuffer->size(); i++) {
```

with msgBuffer being yet another QStringList member of my Class. This piece of code is in the 'onReadyRead()' Slot that gets called when QExtSerialPort has data for me. 
So I think the error is related to that package.

I'm using Qt 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.04 with QExtSerialPort v1.2rc from https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport

Comment: Qt won't share your container behind your back with other threads, those threads are implementation details and shielded from the user. So unless you do explicit multithreading, you should safe in that regard.

Comment: Is sendQueue a local variable or a member? Show the code before the if.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld. Mh, good to know. Or actually bad, bc. now I have no idea what it could be :)
sendQueue is a private member of the class. I thought it might be some stack issue, but if I make it a pointer and allocate with 'new' in the constructor, but then I get an error at ->isEmpty(). I tested it again and it gives me errors with another QList! See updated Question

Comment: looks like some memory management issue, something like bad `static_cast`, dangling pointer and so on. Try run it with valgrind (it is extremely slow, but it will help you find the problem).

Comment: I did run it in Valgrind, but I'm not really getting it. There are some "Invalid read of size 8". Maybe there is an issue bc. I'm storing std::pair in the List. Maybe std ist the problem. (Does sound like STD after all...)

Comment: I think there are some threading issues in the background. I inserted some QMutexes and now I get a deadlock. That's because I'm calling a callback in the the lock, but in that callback I enqueue things in the queue (that's locked)

Comment: OK, it works if I put the critical code from the callback into a slot and just emit a signal in the callback.

Comment: OK no wait. I just forgot to connect the signal and slot. I still get a deadlock...

Comment: Set breakpoints at all places where sendQueue is accessed and check which thread is active, and where the calls come from.

Comment: You may have a re-entrent function being called in a loop or perhaps signals / sloop loop that cause memory corruption which cause crashes at random places.